# Python Django Rest - Return extra field with lowest, highest and average values of some other field

Tags: python, django, rest

I'm new to Django and APIs in general and I want to create a Django based API using Django Rest Framework.

Here's what I want to do:

Endpoint to age range report:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' localhost:8000/reports/employees/age/
```

Response:

```
{
    "younger": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Anakin Skywalker",
        "email": "skywalker@ssys.com.br",
        "department": "Architecture",
        "salary": "4000.00",
        "birth_date": "01-01-1983"},
    "older": {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Obi-Wan Kenobi",
        "email": "kenobi@ssys.com.br",
        "department": "Back-End",
        "salary": "3000.00",
        "birth_date": "01-01-1977"},
    "average": "40.00"
}
```

Endpoint to salary range report:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' localhost:8000/reports/employees/salary/
```

Response:

```
{
    "lowest ": {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Obi-Wan Kenobi",
        "email": "kenobi@ssys.com.br",
        "department": "Back-End",
        "salary": "3000.00",
        "birth_date": "01-01-1977"},
    "highest": {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Leia Organa",
        "email": "organa@ssys.com.br",
        "department": "DevOps",
        "salary": "5000.00",
        "birth_date": "01-01-1980"},
    "average": "4000.00"
}
```

I have two apps, `employees` and `reports`.

Here's **employees/models.py**:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='FirstName LastName')
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=250, default='employee@email.com')
    departament = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='Full-Stack')
    salary = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    birth_date = models.DateField()
```

Here's **employees/serializers.py**:

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'email', 'departament', 'salary', 'birth_date']
```

I'm not sure how to create my views and serializers for my report app. How should I approach this?

How can I return an extra field with a calculation between values of another field? Should I create a custom field in my serializer?

By reading the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/) I've figured that the query I should use should be something like:

```
Employee.objects.aggregate(Max("salary"), Min("salary"), Avg("salary"))
```

Or maybe, for salary for example:

```
Employee.objects.all().order_by('salary')
```

But how would I go about using it?

I don't know where to use or how to go about it as my understanding of APIs and Django Rest Framework is still very lacking.

Should it go in my **reports/view.py**? Or in my **employees/serializers.py**?

Should I create a **reports/serializers.py** file?

Do I need a **reports/model** class with `lowest`, `highest`, `average` fields plus an employee object field?

Should I override the `list()` function of my `ReportSalaryListAPIView` class in my **reports/views.py**? (This class doesn't exist yet)

I'm very lost and confused. Please help point me in the right direction.

Thank you in advance.

---

**Edit:**

My **employees/model.py** now looks like this:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='FirstName LastName')
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=250, default='employee@email.com')
    departament = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='Full-Stack')
    salary = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    birth_date = models.DateField()

    @property
    def get_age(self):
        delta = relativedelta(self.birth_date.days, datetime.today()).years
        return delta

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.age = self.get_age()
        super(Employee, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

My **employees/serializers.py** now:

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'email', 'departament', 'salary', 'birth_date', 'age']
```

I've run the `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands with `manager.py`, just in case.

But I'm now running into this error when trying to create a new employee:

```
'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'days'
```

What is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Idea

No extra fields are needed to store the calculated values since they are calculated based on the rows in the database.

1. First you find `min_salary`, `max_salary`, and `avg_salary` by using the aggregate method.
2. Use found `min_salary` and `max_salary` to find employees.
3. Implement a serializer class that serializes `highest`, `lowest`, and `average` employee salary report.
4. Serialize the `lowest`, `highest`, and `avarage` by using the implemented serializer class.

## Code

In my opinion, the code for performing the logic should be on another layer, usually called the service layer.

```py
# employees/services.py
class EmployeeSalaryReport:
    def __init__(self, lowest, highest, average):
        self.lowest = lowest
        self.highest = highest
        self.average = average

def get_employee_salary_report():
    salary_report_dict = Employee.objects.aggregate(
        min_salary=Min("salary"),
        max_salary=Max("salary"),
        avg_salary=Avg("salary"),
    )
    lowest_salary_employee = Employee.objects.filter(
        salary=salary_report_dict.get("min_salary")
    ).first()
    highest_salary_employee = Employee.objects.filter(
        salary=salary_report_dict.get("max_salary")
    ).first()
    return EmployeeSalaryReport(
        lowest=lowest_salary_employee,
        highest=highest_salary_employee,
        average=salary_report_dict.get("avg_salary"),
    )
```

```py
# employees/serializers.py
class EmployeeSalaryReportSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    lowest = EmployeeSerializer()
    highest = EmployeeSerializer()
    average = serializers.FloatField()
```

```py
# employees/views.py
from rest_framework import views
from rest_framework.response import Response

from employees.services import get_employee_salary_report
from employees.serializers import EmployeeSalaryReportSerializer


class ReportSalaryView(views.APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        employee_salary_report = get_employee_salary_report()
        serializer = EmployeeSalaryReportSerializer(employee_salary_report)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

```py
# employees/urls.py
from django.urls import path

from employees.views import ReportSalaryView


urlpatterns = [
    ...  # other paths
    path("reports/employees/salary/", ReportSalaryView.as_view(), name="report-salary"),
]
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you. I'm trying to do the age report now: So far I've created a calculated field in my **employees/model.py** file for calculating the age. Then I have overridden the `save()` method to include `self.age = self.get_age()`. But now I'm struggling with an error that says `'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'days'`. I've edited the question to include my `get_age` property. Could you please take a look and tell me what's wrong? Thank you very much :)

Comment: Nevermind my last comment. I decided to create a `get_age` method inside my `EmployeeSerializer` and that solved it. I'm marking the question as solved. Thank you very much.